# PHP Warning: require(/vendor/composer/../magento/project-enterprise-edition/app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php): Failed to open stream

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento-upgrade, magento2.4.4

I am working on an upgrade project from Magento 2.3.2.p2 EE to 2.4.4 EE.

After the composer update was done successfully I found the below error while run php bin/magento commands, can anyone help me on the same.

I have already run this `composer dumpautoload` but not still not working.

> $ php bin/magento
> PHP Warning:  require(/home/../vendor/composer/../magento/project-enterprise-edition/app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/../vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 57
> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/home/../vendor/composer/../magento/project-enterprise-edition/app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php' (include_path='/home/../vendor/magento/zendframework1/library:.:/usr/share/php') in /home/../vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:57
> Stack trace:
> #0 /home/../vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(40): composerRequiredb672302d8264da3ebc40879939070dd()
> #1 /home/../vendor/autoload.php(25): ComposerAutoloaderInitdb672302d8264da3ebc40879939070dd::getLoader()
> #2 /home/../app/autoload.php(51): include('...')
> #3 /home/../app/bootstrap.php(43): require_once('...')
> #4 /home/../bin/magento(14): require('...')
> #5 {main}
> thrown in /home/../vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 57

Answer (score 0):

1. `app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php` permissions should be set to 666.
2. If a setting is missing from your composer.json file, some directories will not copy from the Adobe Commerce Code Base. The package and the update/patch can’t apply because files will not be found.

Please change your extra section to match that provided below.

```
"extra":{
  "magento-force": true,
  "magento-deploystrategy": "copy"
}
```

And re-attempt deployment

```
rm -rf vendor
composer install
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

======
For other, who has below issue (the file path does not the same as the Original Poster):
`Warning:  require(/var/www/html/app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`, do the following steps to resolve that issue:

1. Remove the **vendor** directory and clear the **composer cache**:

```
rm -rf vendor
composer clear-cache
```

2. Run the following commands:

```
composer install
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Comment: I have already tried this but this solution is not working for me. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Could you confirm `app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php` exists? If yes, set permissions for this file to 666, and try run bin/magento commands again.

Comment: Yes this file is already exists and permissions is also ok but magento is trying to access this file from vendor/../project-enterprise-edition/app/etc/

Comment: That is correct behavior.

Comment: Should I need to put this file in the vendor/../project-enterprise-edition/app/etc/ folder? commonly this is on app/etc folder right?

Comment: 1. No, you shouldn't do that. Magento will copy all files and directories from `vendor/magento/project-enterprise-edition` to your Magento root directory in case your `vendor directory` or `vendor/magento/project-enterprise-edition` is empty and you run composer install. 2. Yes, that's right.

Comment: Could you add your composer.json to your question? (you can exclude `require` section if you need). And confirm which permission is it for app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php

Comment: Anyway, I've updated my answer, please give it a try. If the issues still persist, then do my above points.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue. The reason was that I had this line line in my composer requirements:

```
"magento/project-community-edition": "2.4.6",
```

But this package is only meant for the installation of Magento. It must not be a requirement in *composer.json* of the project.

Instead the package

```
"magento/product-community-edition": "2.4.6",
```

is needed (please note "product" vs. "project").

After changing this line and running `composer update` everything works as expected again.